# Change class of a menuitem to active if page alias matches menu alias (in a foreach)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, foreach

I got a simple sidemenu that is displayed using a foreach:

```
<?
    if($contentcr[0]['catid'] == '9'){

        foreach($pagecr as $page){
            $landingnospace = str_replace(' ', '_', $page['alias']);
            $title = $page['title'];
            if($title != '') {
            $contentje .= '<li><a href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website1/'.$landingnospace.'.html">'.$title.'</a></li>';  
            }
        }
        echo $contentje;
    }
    else{
        echo 'Alternatief sidemenu';
    }
?>
```

The alias of the page is displayed in the url using .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /_extern/website1/

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Website1
RewriteRule     ^(.*).html content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I am currently using two queries on the page, one for db_content and one for db_categories

db_content:

```
//  content
    $content        = "SELECT * FROM `db_content` WHERE alias = '".$_GET['alias']."' ";
    $contentcon         = $conn->query($content);
    $contentcr          = array();
    while ($contentcr[]     = $contentcon->fetch_array());
```

db_categories

```
//  Pages
$page               = "SELECT con.title, con.alias, con.images, con.introtext
                       FROM db_content con
                       LEFT JOIN db_categories cat ON con.catid = cat.id
                       AND cat.alias = '".$_GET['alias']."' WHERE con.state = 1 ORDER BY `ordering` DESC"; 
$pagecon            = $conn->query($page);
$pagecr             = array();
while ($pagecr[]    = $pagecon->fetch_array());
```

So how can I compare the results in the foreach to the alias in the url, and if they match add the class: `current-menu-item` to the list tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a `$class` variable and see if the current `$page["alias"]` equals the `$_GET["alias"]`. If so, apply the class `current-menu-item`, if not, leave it blank.

```
<?
    if($contentcr[0]['catid'] == '9'){

        $alias = $_GET["alias"];

        foreach($pagecr as $page){
            $landingnospace = str_replace(' ', '_', $page['alias']);
            $title = $page['title'];
            if($title != '') {
                // magic happens here
                $class = ($page["alias"] == $alias)?"current-menu-item":"";
                $contentje .= '<li><a class="'.$class.'" href="http://www.website.nl/_extern/website1/'.$landingnospace.'.html">'.$title.'</a></li>';  
            }
        }
        echo $contentje;
    }
    else{
        echo 'Alternatief sidemenu';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does that work like that? Adding a questionmark after appointing the variable?

Comment: Nevermind, you added the class to the anchor tag, I changed it to the list tag and it works like I wanted :) Thanks!

Comment: @twan: It works like that as it is a comparison. Anyway, glad to help.